# Правильный вывод блоков html через js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Обычно я добавляю а страницу код, полученный через js таким способом. Но может есть какой-то более удобный метод?

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if ($data.data.MOW[i]) {
        $html.append(
        '<p>Пользователь: <span class="user">' + user.nickname + '</p>')
    }
}
```

Comment: шаблоны и шаблонизаторы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от того, что для вас "удобно".

**Оптимизация**

Манипуляции с DOM всегда занимают много времени, поэтому нужно минимизировать кол-во обращений к DOM, учитывая, что вы делаете это в цикле.

```
var html = [];
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if ($data.data.MOW[i]) {
    html.push('<p>Пользователь: <span class="user">' + user.nickname + '</p>');
  }
}
$html.append(html.join('\n'));
```

**Шаблонные строки (ES6)**

В новой спецификации ECMAScript 6 появились '[шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)'.

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if ($data.data.MOW[i]) {
    $html.append(
    `<p>Пользователь: <span class="user">${user.nickname}</p>`)
  }
}
```

Конечно же можно объединить оба способа выше.

**Шаблонизатор**

Все (ну или почти) шаблонизаторы имеют возможность работы с циклами для отрисовки элементов. Из шаблонизаторов я бы посоветовал doT.js (статья [doT.js + jQuery](http://nano.sapegin.ru/all/shablony-dlya-javascript-dot-js-plagin-dlya-jquery)). Но не одним doT.js едины, есть еще много разных шаблонизаторов, из которых вы можете выбрать на свой вкус [тут](https://garann.github.io/template-chooser/).